# How to display event attachment on an embedded Outlook Calendar? And how to add an "add to my calendar button?

Tags: html, outlook

So I'm in the process of making a webpage that as an embedded outlook calendar.  This is my html for the embedded calendar:

```
#wrap {
width:1000px;
height:900px;
padding:0;
position:relative;
left:0px;
top:0px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#frame {
width:1000px;
height:900px;
position:relative;
left:0px;
top:0px;
}
#frame {
-ms-zoom:0.7;
}
</style>
<div id="wrap" unselectable="on">
<iframe id="frame" src="[calendar link]"></iframe>
```

The calendar appears correctly on my webpage, but I'd like to be able to see any event attachments such as a pdf of meeting minutes.  I'd also like for there to be a button where someone can add the calendar to their own outlook calendar.

I'd also accept a link to some documentation on how to do this as an answer.

Please keep in mind the I'm very new to web development.

Thanks in advance.